# .NET Maui Blazor, SaveFile Implementation

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, .net-7.0

I have a project that is a Blazor Hybrid using Maui .NET. There exists the method FilePicker which allows you to open a file from the computer. However I cannot find a method to SAVE a file to the computer? May anyone know if this exists or how I can accomplish this if it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `SaveFile service` with the `SaveFile Implemtation`.Here's the code snippet below for the WinUI example that you can refer to:

```
public sealed class SaveFile : ISaveFile
{
    public async ValueTask SaveFileAsync(string filename, Stream stream)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        var fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = filename;
        fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(extension, new List<string> { extension });

        if (MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Application.Windows[0].Handler.PlatformView is MauiWinUIWindow window)
        {
            WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(fileSavePicker, window.WindowHandle);
        }

        var result = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            using (var fileStream = await result.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                fileStream.SetLength(0); // override
                await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running into an issue with this code. It says that MauiWinUIApplication does not exist in the current context and that I might be missing the namespace for MauiWinUIWindow and that WinRT does not exist in the current context. Not sure what @using library stores these objects.

Comment: You might need wrap the code with `#if WINDOWS  #endif`. As I said, the code example is for WinUI, you need to make small adjustments if you want it work.